# $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy","10/10/2010");  not cuasing an Exception?

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy","10/10/2010");
```

Why this not causing an Exception?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything looks fine to me. You do know that `yy` represents a four digit year despite being only two characters long, right?

Comment: ooo really? i was not knowing that

Comment: one note:$.datepicker.parseDate can onlyvalidate a date picked using date picker

Comment: @user444569: I don't quite understand what that means. `$.datepicker.parseDate` just takes in a normal strings, it has no idea where it originally came from. Are you sure you're not confusing the problem with something else, such as forgetting to include jQuery UI on the page where you're trying to use the function?